# Could those named "User XXXX" please consider changing their names to something more distinctive?

Tags: discussion

It might be completely unremarkable if there were only a couple of such names on this server, but lately there are many people now going by monikers such as user3432 and user5633, who've accumulated a fair bit of reputation.  Here are a couple of reasons why I think continuing in that way is bad:

- I like associating names to identities, as certain posters have distinct expertise. Suppose you're looking for good answers on say, set theory -- you might decide to ready daily some of User A's answers. Or if you're looking for number theory, you might to decide to read all of User B's.  Names that don't vary much from each other, like "UserXXXX," make it hard to remember the identity of posters you want to keep track of.
- Related is that "userXXXX" names make it hard to search.  If one person's username differs from another person's name in only a couple of places, one has to needlessly memorize an arbitrary 4 or 5 digit string just to locate a unique user.  Why? Everyone wants to be read and sought out; keeping "userXXXX" makes that harder for essentially no reason.
- Allowing default usernames encourages bad behavior, by muddling identities.   For example, I know quite a few people who blog on Blogspot who will not allow comments to their posts with the default "Anonymous." They force everyone to choose a unique name.  Why?  One reason is that some people will nefariously hide behind "userXXXX" type usernames to make spam posts that will not be immediately recognized for flagging.   What's more important here is that simply picking out a username and assuming a unique identity is an investment in of itself, and signals that one wants to become involved, and is not simply a passive member of the community.  It demonstrates engagement.

I understand the need some feel to be relatively anonymous; that's fine, I too like to keep many of Internet identities separate from one another.  And, choosing a unique username might seem flippant and unimportant matter compared to the main mission of the site, asking and answering questions.   But if that's true, the answer isn't to stick with "userXXXX" -- better to go to a goobledygook concatenation of words or something than to stick with that.

Comment: An obvious exception would user02138; the difference is that his ending 5 digit string has obvious semantic meaning, and thus is easy to memorize and to use for mental identification.

Comment: for the record, users are presented with a must-dismiss top notification bar at sign up pointing them *directly* to the profile edit page, and *specifically* asking them to enter their name and email as appropriate.

Comment: @billare Good points, btw what is the semantic meaning of 02138?

Comment: @solomoan: It refers to the ZIP code of Harvard University.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/usernames-that-say-more

Comment: In terms of policy, you can't do much more than prod these users. But on the individual level, people could refuse to answer questions by these users and instead comment on the questions, giving their reasons. Ultimately, nobody will do something _you_ want him to do, unless you give him a good egoistic reason to do it.

Comment: @Alex Bartel I hope you do not read answers from anonymous users with high reputation, either. Would you think it appropriate to not answer your questions to give you an egoistic reason to stop your practice of not answering anonymous questions? You suggest to not answer questions of people who - by their reputation - answered other people's questions. @Billare How can an anonymous user with high reputation be considered *lazy* just because they do not do what you want them to do?

Comment: @user9325 Because it's **obviously** good form, as attested by the number of upvotes my post has received; if you have competing reasons why not changing the default name is preferable -- even into alternate forms of gibberish! -- please, do feel free to air them out in an answer.

Comment: @Billare: You did *not* ask why I did not choose a username, you listed a reason why *you* want me to have a recognizable username: To be able to read specifically what I write. The other reasons - spamming and "laziness"- are not convincing in view of the reputation system.

Comment: @Billare: As for my reasons: 1. Want to look around and post a while before deciding on the level of anonymity reflected in my username. 2. To get "involved" in the personal non-math sense did *not* seem attractive after reading some of the recent meta-threads. 3. To read in this thread that some people will not answer well-posed questions by me even though I have clearly answered other questions just to enforce their preferences on "good form" unrelated to the question does not have the desired effect on me.

Comment: @user9325 I did not write about "you" at all.  I wrote about a general class of users.  If your sensibilities are offended by being called lazy for not performing what I -- and others -- consider a miniscule change, feel free to exempt yourself! I'll suppose I'll appeal to the others all the more.  Also, don't presume that I'm particularly interested in "your" answers; the case may I be wrote this simply because you, and potential others who may not be as aware, may cause confusion with a far more prolific user9352 -- so-called "likelihood of confusion", a staple doctrine of trademark law.

Comment: @user9325 Note that Alex Bartel's comment isn't particularly upvoted.   I thought it overly harsh myself; I personally think that most of these default usernames are keeping their style not out of malice, but simply out of not being aware of the possible confusion they cause.  I didn't express my thoughts on that harshness because Alex's comment had been posted when the topic had been dead for some time.  It was pointless to pursue.

Comment: @user9325 Your reason number #2 doesn't make much sense either.   One can have an identity, a recognizable identity -- such as **Billare** -- that is not connected with one's real-life persona ("Ulysses N. Owen"; "U.N. Owen", "unknown").  My changing my name to Billare did not make me "involved in the **personal** non-math sense."

Comment: @Billare, either a name is unique, or it isn't. There's no such thing as "more unique." Please edit your question in accordance with this observation.

Comment: Indeed a profound observation.  3 things though: English is not binary logic; many dictionaries, including the OED, define _unique_ as "having a rare quality"; [the Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/x3.asp?xx=1&w10=more&w11=unique&r=) attests 38 usages from newspapers as lowbrow as _USA Today_ to as august as _Foreign Affairs_.   I even find a usage in the New York Times' _On Language_ column.  If it's good enough for the _Times_....

Comment: @Billare Although, on one hand, I can sympathize with some of your remarks, on the other hand I find it a bit ironic that in a *math* forum one is objecting to usernames containing *numbers* as not being "unique" enough. The law of small numbers guarantees many interesting properties of these small numbers besides zipcodes (recall Ramanujan and taxicabs). To a mathematician, some of these numbers should have more meaning than a random surname!

Comment: @Billare: You have given ample usage and exception for your phrasing.  But a very simple modification would be to replace "unique" by "distinctive" in the title of this question. I presume that mathematically minded people on this site would appreciate this choice of words, and it would be a better introduction to the reasonings you give in the body of your argumentation.

Comment: @Gerry: I've moved your answer to a comment after several users flagged it as "not an answer" and possibly downvoted it because of that.

Comment: @Gerry: While I understand that you feel strongly about this, reasonable minds differ on this subject. See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique?show=0&t=1303775569), [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/more+unique?qsrc=2446) for the usage note, and [here](http://www.stevecooper.org/index.php/2009/09/01/grammar-rant-1-more-unique/) for a more informal discussion.

Comment: @Willie, thanks, of course it should have been a comment, not an answer. I'll try to be more careful in the future.